# Creating textfield in Viewcontroller and resigning textfield in NsObject class

Tags: objective-c, iphone, textfield

I have to resign textfield that has created in a view controller, and need to resign that textfield in an NSObject class. If I create an object for the view controller in NSObject it will create an new instance and can’t able to access that textfield. My code is

ViewController.m

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
         cardNo1=[self createTextField:80  :230 :45 :26 :@"Helvetica Light":NSTextAlignmentCenter];

         cardNo2=[self createTextField:128 :230 :45 :26 :@"Helvetica Light":NSTextAlignmentCenter];
         cardNo3=[self createTextField:176 :230 :45 :26 :@"Helvetica Light":NSTextAlignmentCenter];
         cardNo4=[self createTextField:224 :230 :45 :26 :@"Helvetica Light":NSTextAlignmentCenter];
         cardNo5=[self createTextField:272 :230 :35 :26 :@"Helvetica Light":NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    }
```

NSObject.m

```
-(void)_timerFired
{
    ViewContoller *iphoneobj=[[ViewContoller alloc]init];
    [iphoneobj1.cardNo1 resignFirstResponder];
    [iphoneobj1.cardNo2 resignFirstResponder];
    [iphoneobj1.cardNo3 resignFirstResponder];
    [iphoneobj1.cardNo4 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

In NSObject class it will create an new instance for view controller, so cardNo1, cardNo2, etc will return nil object, Can any one suggest how to resign text field in NSObject class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this, if you are allocating your view controller then inside that you need to initialise your textfield also after that only you can access it. So try to modify your code in such a way that you should not alloc init your view controller inside your `timerFired` method. But instead you can directly check the instance of your view controller and if exist then try to access the textfield.

Comment: Thats what i am explaining you need to initialise you view controller in some other place

Comment: I have initialized my view controller object(iphoneobj) in init method of NSObject class and i am using that instance to access the textfield cardno1,but cardno1 value is still nil;

Comment: Whenever you initialise your view controller at that moment your all object present inside will be reset. So you need to initialise your text field after creating you view controller

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer by creating an object of that view controller in NSObject class and the value of that object will be assigned in view controller class and i will access my textfield using that object in NsObject class.